# Installing an emulator in Android studio; failing to install HXAM

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

I have installed Flutter and have no Issues in Flutter doctor; however if i try to download an emulator in android studio, AS says i have to install  HXAM. I have enabled Virtualization in BIOS (HP Zbook), but still says:

> 'C:\Users\BARNABAS' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Failing to use an android emulator in VS code because HXAM is not installing. I have enabled virtualization in BIOS, but android studios keeps printing

> 'C:\Users\BARNABAS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: AMD processor ?